# how to insert a base64 encoded image in MS Word that updates automatically

Tags: html, ms-word, base64

I tried quick parts -> field -> links and references -> includePicture
and copied the URI:

data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KXLlwYMWLEsGHDLl++PHv2bJ1OV6dOnaFDh3LZFi9LRggUL9u/fL5VK27RpM3bs2PXr1+t0Om9v78zMzFmzZjk6OtrZ2a1bt47H4w0ZMiQ1NTU7O

in field properties. But the MS Word doesn't support based64 encoded data.
Does anyone know a way to link such images from html in MS Word?

Thanks a lot!